# Moving around Java references

Tags: java

So I am creating a Binary Tree through recursion, When I insert a new node I would like to jump back up to the root to start the insert from scratch again. to do that I follow this routine.

```
BinaryTree node = new BinaryTree();
node = this;
node = root; // this is where I want to get to
```

So when I coded this out and attempted to set the $this variable to root it did not set as can be seen in this picture.
[image]
Why is 'this' not set this to root? how can I jump to the top of a tree?

```
 public void addNode(List teams, BinaryTree tree, BinaryTree root){
        while(teams.size() > 1){
            print(root);
            //Half's the list
            halfA = teams.subList(0, teams.size() / 2);
            halfB = teams.subList(teams.size() / 2, teams.size());

            if(parent == null){
                left = new BinaryTree(halfA);
                left.parent = this;
                right = new BinaryTree(halfB);
                right.parent = this;
            }

            if(countChildren(tree.left) >= countChildren(tree.right)) {
                if (right == null) {
                    setRight(new BinaryTree(halfB));
                        BinaryTree temp = new BinaryTree();
                        parent = this;
                        temp = this;
                        temp = tree;

                } else if (right != null)
                    right.addNode(halfB, tree, root);
            }
            if(countChildren(tree.right) >= countChildren(tree.left)) {
                if (left == null) {
                    setLeft(new BinaryTree(halfA));
                        BinaryTree temp = new BinaryTree();
                        parent = this;
                        temp = this;
                        temp = tree;
                } else if (left != null)
                    left.addNode(halfA, tree, root);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please copy your full method into the question instead of using a screenshot?

Comment: Do not screenshot your code... just post it.

Comment: `this` cannot be reassigned. If you do `node=this;` followed by `node=something else;` the first assignment is pointless. It's like saying "Let x be one. Actually, let x be two".